# Missing gem watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

```
ahmet@Ubuntu:~/test$ ruby hello.rb
/home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- watir (LoadError)
    from /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from hello.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I have required rubygems in my .rb but still get this error

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Watir Readme](https://github.com/watir/watir) you have to install and require `firewatir`. Also you may want to install [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem with a different gem a while back on Ubuntu using RVM. I *know* the gem was installed, because I had just installed it. I did the following:

```
rvm get latest
rvm reload
gem update --system
```

Then for good measure I reinstalled the gem, and everything worked. Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md

Comment: Man that book is great, who in the world wrote it?

Comment: I was kidding, but I'm glad it's now part of a Stack answer in case anyone was curious!

Comment: Maybe I would get the joke at another time, but I saw it after being awake for 20-30 hours, so my brain was not at 100%. :)

Answer (score 1):

The require should be either 'firewatir' or 'watir-webdriver'

```
require 'firewatir'
```

or

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
```